# Aggregate on array of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection with multiple documents. Each document has an array with multiple subdocuments (or embedded documents i guess?). Each of these subdocuments is in this format:

```
{
    "name": string,
    "count": integer
}
```

Now I want to aggregate these subdocuments to find

1. The top X counts and their name.
2. Same as 1. but the names have to match a regex before sorting and limiting.

I have tried the following for 1. already - it does return me the top X but unordered, so I'd have to order them again which seems somewhat inefficient.

```
[{
    $match: {
        _id: id
}
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$array"
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        'count': -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: x
}]
```

Since i'm rather new to mongodb this is pretty confusing for me. Happy for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort has to include the array name in order to avoid an additional sort later on.

Given the following document to work with:

```
    {
      students: [{
        count: 4,
        name: "Ann"
      }, {
        count: 7,
        name: "Brad"
      }, {
        count: 6,
        name: "Beth"
      }, {
        count: 8,
        name: "Catherine"
      }]
    }
```

As an example, the following aggregation query will match any name containing the letters "h" and "e". This needs to happen after the "$unwind" step in order to only keep the ones you need.

```
    db.tests.aggregate([
      {$match: {
        _id: ObjectId("5c1b191b251d9663f4e3ce65")
      }},
      {$unwind: {
        path: "$students"
      }},
      {$match: {
        "students.name": /[he]/
      }},
      {$sort: {
        "students.count": -1
      }},
      {$limit: 2}
    ])
```

This is the output given the above mentioned input:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c1b191b251d9663f4e3ce65"), "students" : { "count" : 8, "name" : "Catherine" } }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c1b191b251d9663f4e3ce65"), "students" : { "count" : 6, "name" : "Beth" } }
```

Both names contain the letters "h" and "e", and the output is sorted from high to low.

When setting the limit to 1, the output is limited to:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c1b191b251d9663f4e3ce65"), "students" : { "count" : 8, "name" : "Catherine" } }
```

In this case only the highest count has been kept after having matched the names.

=====================
Edit for the extra question:

Yes, the first $match can be changed to filter on specific universities.

```
      {$match: {
        university: "University X"
      }},
```

That will give one or more matching documents (in case you have a document per year or so) and the rest of the aggregation steps would still be valid.

The following match would retrieve the students for the given university for a given academic year in case that would be needed.

```
      {$match: {
        university: "University X",
        academic_year: "2018-2019"
      }},
```

That should narrow it down to get the correct documents.

Comment: Thank you! As a bonus question: can i change the first `$match` to match a key that exists once in every document instead of the `_id`? Let's say each document has a key `university` and i only want to find students from one specific university.

Comment: Sure. Just edited the answer to include the bonus question.